Dagger2 multi-binding into a map with kotlin sealed class as key
In an android app, I'm using dagger2 for DI. I'm trying to multi-bind into a map, but getting build failures as shown below.
I have this module class in web module:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RequestModule {
  @Provides
  @IntoMap
  @ClassKey(ProcessRequest.Web::class)
  fun bindWebRequestProcessor(webRequestProcessor: WebRequestProcessor) =
    webRequestProcessor
}

Where WebRequestProcessor is:
class WebRequestProcessor @Inject constructor() : RequestProcessor<ProcessRequest.Web> {
      fun process(request: ProcessRequest.Web){}
}

In base module:
RequestProcessor is an interface:
interface RequestProcessor<T: ProcessRequest> {
  fun process(request: T)
}

ProcessRequest is a sealed class as follows:
sealed class ProcessRequest {
  abstract val param: Param

  data class Web(val message: Message) : ProcessRequest() {
    override val param: Param?
      get() = message.param
  }
}

It is the injected in the below class as follows:
@Singleton
class ProcessScheduler
@Inject
constructor(private val requestProcessors: Map<ProcessRequest, @JvmSuppressWildcards RequestProcessor<ProcessRequest>>){}

web module has a dependency on base module.
However, this throws a build error:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<com.example.ProcessRequest,? extends com.example.RequestProcessor<com.example.ProcessRequest>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
I have tried creating and adding a @Qualifier annotation to the bindWebRequestProcessor method and the map being injected in ProcessScheduler, but get the same error.
Anyone have any suggestions?

@ClassKey means using the class as a key. @ClassKey(ProcessRequest.Web::class) indicates that your binding would be of type Map<Class<?>, RequestProcessor<ProcessorRequest>>.
If you want to use instances of a sealed class as a key, you'll need to make your own replacement annotation and annotate the annotation with @MapKey.
@MapKey
annotation class ProcessRequestKey(val value: ProcessRequest)

It isn't immediately clear why your error message refers to ? extends RequestProcessor<ProcessRequest>> as a bounded wildcard despite your correct-looking usage of @JvmSuppressWildcards. Perhaps it's a stale error message or alluding to a non-updated injection point other than the one you listed. In either case you'll need to switch to a Map<Class<?>, RequestProcessor<ProcessRequest>> injection for @ClassKey or make your own injection with @MapKey before this will start to work.
